# How to detect if connected to Twitter account in device, from my Android Application?

Tags: android, android-twitter

Let me try to be clear with what I want. 
I have a button, and when I click on the button, I want to detect if there is any active twitter session in the device, or am I logged in into a twitter account in my device. If I am connected, I want to use the twitter account, somehow save the session in my application and use it when I want to share something via twitter in my application without having to log in again.

Most example I found is tweeting from my application itself, for example this http://www.androidhive.info/2012/09/android-twitter-oauth-connect-tutorial/

I just wanna detect, if I'm connected to a twitter account, I wanna use it in my app, and use them when I call Share Intent.

Answer (score 0):

you can find this method in TwitterApp.java (twitter4j)

```
public boolean isAuthenticated() {    
        try {
            AccessToken a = mSession.getAccessToken();
            mTwitter = new TwitterFactory().getInstance();
            mTwitter.setOAuthConsumer(Constants.CONSUMER_KEY,
                    Constants.CONSUMER_SECRET);
            mTwitter.setOAuthAccessToken(a);    

            try {
                mTwitter.getAccountSettings();
                return true;
            } catch (TwitterException e) {
                return false;
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Comment: thanks. will give this a try @talhakosen. but what if I don't have any consumer key and consumer secret? I just want the user to share some item in the app via their own account.

Comment: You can use shareintent to do this

Comment: yeah i am aware of that. but my application has a share setting where i can connect to my twitter account/detect existing session from device and store the session in my app. and from there my share intent will detect the twitter account and share. my problem lies in the share setting part.

Comment: So you have to create a twitter app and get consumer and secret keys.

Comment: Alright, I will do that. After that I will try out the options here and pick the best answer :) Thank you so much for your time.

Comment: It will be easy thera are only 2 answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Get this default value of preference

`this.prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);`

And with the help of this value check the authentication using isAuthenticated method, which is written below

```
if (TwitterUtils.isAuthenticated(prefs)) {

                    sendTweet();
                } else {
                    Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), PrepareRequestTokenActivity.class);
                       startActivity(i);
                }
public static boolean isAuthenticated(SharedPreferences prefs) {

    String token = prefs.getString(OAuth.OAUTH_TOKEN, "");
    String secret = prefs.getString(OAuth.OAUTH_TOKEN_SECRET, "");

    AccessToken a = new AccessToken(token,secret);
    Twitter twitter = new TwitterFactory().getInstance();
    twitter.setOAuthConsumer(Constants.CONSUMER_KEY, Constants.CONSUMER_SECRET);
    twitter.setOAuthAccessToken(a);

    try {
        twitter.getAccountSettings();
        return true;
    } catch (TwitterException e) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks @Tahreem. will give this a try. just as i mentioned in the comment above, what if I don't have any consumer key and consumer secret? and i don't think i need one for my application. hope you have the time to guide me.

Comment: when u create application account on twitter.dev.com, u get consumer key and secret. U have to put these two values in the Constants class of app, which is must for authentication.
u can get the sample project from here. This project contains constant.java file and code snippet that i wrote above.

Comment: this is a very nice tutorial, that gives you the information of every step.
http://android10.org/index.php/articleslibraries/291-twitter-integration-in-your-android-application
U can find useful information according to your requirement from above mentioned link and project.